# Can't get a json of arrays from my .php file

Tags: swift

I am quite new in the Swift 3.0 world and I'm trying to get a json full of some arrays that describe a book. This is my code:

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string:"http://chuadiv.ddns.net/easytoschool/fetch_book_detailed.php");

                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl as! URL);
                request.httpMethod = "POST";
                let postString = "name=\(libro)";
                request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
                    data, response, error in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("error=\(error)")
                        return
                    }
                    var err: NSError?
                    do {
                        var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSArray
                        if let parseJSON: NSArray = json {
                            for index in 0...parseJSON.count-1 {
                                let libro = parseJSON[index] as! NSArray
                                print((libro[0] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "id"))
                                print((libro[0] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "id"))
                            }
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("error=\(error)")
                        return
                    }
                }
                task.resume();
```

"libro" is a string that I pass to the .php file with the method POST

Here is the json that is returned from the .php file that I have written:

```
[{"id":"19","name":"CHIMICA","author":"MASSIMO CAFARDA","school":"PILATI","price":"20","status":"Come nuovo","isbn":"0987654321123","type":"IN VENDITA","idSeller":"2","nameSeller":"Stefano","surnameSeller":"Zanella"}]
```

I have tried to find some material, but I can't get a json WITHOUT the name of the arrays

Can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: At the beginning I want to print the first book of the array

Comment: When I learn how to do it, I move on. (In my code I have written "id" two times, but the second should be "name")

Comment: Sorry, now it should work

Comment: You use Swift 3? Then try to avoid at best all classes that have `NS` Prefix, like `NSArray` to Swift Type versions `[Any]` etc. `let libro = parseJSON[index] as! NSArray` That's a Dict, not an array. So it should be `let libro = parseJSON[index] as [String:Any];` and then `print(\(libro["id"]));`